# Is there a way to have a string parameter in method that suggests MVC controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, intellisense

In MVC when you use the UrlHelper class to specify a controller and action Intellisense will suggest names of controllers and actions as you type. Is that feature just built into Visual Studio to know to suggest that, or is there some way I could get a method parameter in a custom method to also suggest those to the user?

Hopefully, that makes sense.

Comment: resharper has that. you just attribute it with the right annotation

Comment: oh gotcha. Do you know what attribute I need to use?